# How to store user created objects in a List Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to store my user created objects in a List to be displayed in a ListView but I am getting an error :

[image]

The error it gives me is this :
The instance member `contact1` can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different `expressiondartimplicit_this_reference_in_initializer`

How do I achieve storing a user object in a List ?

Comment: Add the code and not the image please.

Comment: put myList inside the build method

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this :

**This is an Example Change it based on your data**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Contact {
  final String id;
  final int number;
  final String role;

  Contact({this.id, this.number, this.role});
}

class Widget1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var contact1 = Contact(id: "fahmi", number: 00, role: "admin");
    var contact2 = Contact(id: "fahmi", number: 00, role: "admin");
    var contact3 = Contact(id: "fahmi", number: 00, role: "admin");
    final List<Contact> myList = [contact1, contact2, contact3];
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't be accessed any object in the initializer position. Just set the items to the `myList` in inside the `initState` or any of the methods. the best way is to set it inside the `initState` method. because it will be called only once.

1. Just initialize the `myList` in outside of the stateless class.
2. Add items to the `myList` in initState.

```
class ContactsPage extends StatelessWidget {

 final List<Contact> myList = [];

 final Contact contact1 = Contact(id: "fahmi", number: 00, role: "admin");
 final Contact contact2 = Contact(id: "fahmi", number: 00, role: "admin");
 final Contact contact3 = Contact(id: "fahmi", number: 00, role: "admin");

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   myList.addAll([contact1, contact2, contact]);
 }
}
```